# Search for line which includes any character other than

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm writing a simple DNA sequencing program using **ruby**. I need to understand if a `String` has **any other** character than `ACTG`. For example:

This is a DNA codon sequence: `ACTGCGTAG`

This is an AA sequence: `ACACLG`, `ACTG`

How can I do it like this using regular expressions?

Thanks

Comment: Remember that not everyone is familiar with DNA and its sequence. So it's not really clear what the expected output is.

Comment: @HamZa Sure, you're right sorry. Any string that will contain a character other than 'A', 'C', 'T', 'G' (in my case) is an AA sequence, hence a *valid* string. Order doesn't matter, might be `GTACACACA` for an invalid string and `ACLTG` for a valid one.

Comment: `string.include?('ACTG')`

Comment: @Kris that won't work because in my case I'm not looking for a specific sequence. I'm looking for *any other character*. Might have a string that goes like `ACTCTCTCTC` still a codon not an AA.

Comment: I think you need to clarify the question, its unclear. Who knows what a codon and AA are...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand it correctly,

`!str.match(/[^ACTG]/)` should solve your problem.

For example

`!"ACTGCGTAG".match(/[^ACTG]/)` returns `true`.

while

`!"ACACLG".match(/[^ACTG]/)` return `false`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

`[^ACGT]` with the `m` tag enabled

Comment: It seems that `ACGT` is a __sequence__.  This wouldn't detect `ACGTC`.

Comment: No actually it's correct.